# Firebase Google Auth: Getting 'The identity provider configuration is disabled' even though it is enabled

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm getting 'The identity provider configuration is disabled' from Firebase Google Authorization even though it is clearly enabled in the Firebase console. It doesn't happen for all Google accounts.

[image: Firebase console]

Is anyone aware of any other reasons why this error message would be the response from the Firebase Authorization server? This is a web-app.

Comment: This typically means that your app is connected to a different Firebase project than the one you have open in the console. You might want to double check the configuration data in your app to ensure you're looking at the same project.